# Flutter Unit test http mock returns 400 when it should return 200

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Not really sure what's going on, and every tutorial I find seems to set things up the same way.

Essentially I've mocked out an `http.client` using [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) and I'm trying to stub an http get request like so:

```
test("Return 'has_on_boarded' when firebaseUid is valid", () async {
      final client = MockClient();

      const uid = "123";

      when(client.get(Uri.parse("${dotenv.env['BASE_API_URL']}/users/$uid")))
          .thenAnswer((_) async =>
              http.Response('{"user":{"has_onboarded":true}}', 200));

      expect(await UserRepository().initialize(client, uid), "has_on_boarded");
});
```

For some reason, I only get 400s and not the 200 or body I'm telling it to return with.

**Update:**

Here is the [Flutter tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking) I'm using.

I did discover that using `testwidgetsflutterbinding` makes all http requests return 400, though since it is being mocked that seems weird.

I've removed that part, however, while it's no longer erroring `http.Response('{"user":{"has_onboarded":true}}` still resulting in `{"user":{"has_onboarded":true}}` being returned...

Comment: You really should be using `package:http'`s [`MockClient`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http.testing/MockClient-class.html) class.  It's far less error-prone than trying to mock it yourself Mockito since Mockito will return the stubbed responses only if the stubbed call matches *exactly*.

Comment: @jamesdlin Flutter's own example does it this way. I find it hard to believe this can't work. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking

Comment: Using Mockito to mock `http.Client` *can* work, but as I said, it's a *lot* easier to use `MockClient`. https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/6924